# Out of memory error when adding comboboxes to userForm

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have a MS Word document which has vba macro. I have too many comboboxes in my userform. After a point i can not add a new comboboxes. When I click to view code button, it gives me out of memory error. I'm adding my userForm to below.

[image: userForm]

My vba codes are like this

```
Private Sub UserForm_Activate()
hpcStage4
End Sub
Private Sub hpcStage4()
    Me.cmbHPC4_1.List = Array("Serviceable", "Unserviceable", "N/A per WS")
    Me.cmbHPC4_2.List = Array("Serviceable", "Unserviceable", "N/A per WS")
    Me.cmbHPC4_3.List = Array("Serviceable", "Unserviceable", "N/A per WS")
    Me.cmbHPC4_4.List = Array("Serviceable", "Unserviceable", "N/A per WS")
    Me.cmbHPC4_5.List = Array("Serviceable", "Unserviceable", "N/A per WS")
    Me.cmbHPC4_6.List = Array("Serviceable", "Unserviceable", "N/A per WS")
    Me.cmbHPC4_7.List = Array("Serviceable", "Unserviceable", "N/A per WS")
    Me.cmbHPC4_8.List = Array("Serviceable", "Unserviceable", "N/A per WS")
    Me.cmbHPC4_9.List = Array("Serviceable", "Unserviceable", "N/A per WS")
    Me.cmbHPC4_10.List = Array("Serviceable", "Unserviceable", "N/A per WS")
    Me.cmbHPC4_11.List = Array("Dent", "Nick", "Coating Damage", "Organic Redidues", "Dirt", "Trace", "Deposits", "Mineral Deposits", "Superficial Imperfection", "Scratch", "Scored", "Crack", "Axial Crack", "Radial Crack", "Circumferencial Crack", "Chordwise Crack", "Tip Connected Radial Crack", "Connected Loop Crack", "Full Crack", "Multi Cracks", "Tight Crack", "Burn", "Edge Burnback", "Burn Hole", "LE Burn Hole", "Burn Through Hole", "Burn Through", "Corrosion", "Discoloration", "Oxidation", "Sulphidation", "Erosion", "Blistering", "Pitting", "Peeling", "Ceramic Coating Detachment", "Missing Thermal Barrier Coating", "Tip rub", "Burr", "Curled", "Tip Curled", "Tip Corner Curled", "Missing Tip Corner", "Overlap", "Shingling", "Unlatching", "Out Of Flush", "Missing Material", "Missing Piece", "Chipped", "Flaking", "Lift Up", "Bulging", "Spalled", "Bent", "Distortion", "Tear", "Torn", "Wear", "Worn", "Plugged Air Slot", "Damper Wire Extrusion")
    Me.cmbHPC4_12.List = Array("Dent", "Nick", "Coating Damage", "Organic Redidues", "Dirt", "Trace", "Deposits", "Mineral Deposits", "Superficial Imperfection", "Scratch", "Scored", "Crack", "Axial Crack", "Radial Crack", "Circumferencial Crack", "Chordwise Crack", "Tip Connected Radial Crack", "Connected Loop Crack", "Full Crack", "Multi Cracks", "Tight Crack", "Burn", "Edge Burnback", "Burn Hole", "LE Burn Hole", "Burn Through Hole", "Burn Through", "Corrosion", "Discoloration", "Oxidation", "Sulphidation", "Erosion", "Blistering", "Pitting", "Peeling", "Ceramic Coating Detachment", "Missing Thermal Barrier Coating", "Tip rub", "Burr", "Curled", "Tip Curled", "Tip Corner Curled", "Missing Tip Corner", "Overlap", "Shingling", "Unlatching", "Out Of Flush", "Missing Material", "Missing Piece", "Chipped", "Flaking", "Lift Up", "Bulging", "Spalled", "Bent", "Distortion", "Tear", "Torn", "Wear", "Worn", "Plugged Air Slot", "Damper Wire Extrusion")
    Me.cmbHPC4_13.List = Array("Dent", "Nick", "Coating Damage", "Organic Redidues", "Dirt", "Trace", "Deposits", "Mineral Deposits", "Superficial Imperfection", "Scratch", "Scored", "Crack", "Axial Crack", "Radial Crack", "Circumferencial Crack", "Chordwise Crack", "Tip Connected Radial Crack", "Connected Loop Crack", "Full Crack", "Multi Cracks", "Tight Crack", "Burn", "Edge Burnback", "Burn Hole", "LE Burn Hole", "Burn Through Hole", "Burn Through", "Corrosion", "Discoloration", "Oxidation", "Sulphidation", "Erosion", "Blistering", "Pitting", "Peeling", "Ceramic Coating Detachment", "Missing Thermal Barrier Coating", "Tip rub", "Burr", "Curled", "Tip Curled", "Tip Corner Curled", "Missing Tip Corner", "Overlap", "Shingling", "Unlatching", "Out Of Flush", "Missing Material", "Missing Piece", "Chipped", "Flaking", "Lift Up", "Bulging", "Spalled", "Bent", "Distortion", "Tear", "Torn", "Wear", "Worn", "Plugged Air Slot", "Damper Wire Extrusion")
    Me.cmbHPC4_14.List = Array("Dent", "Nick", "Coating Damage", "Organic Redidues", "Dirt", "Trace", "Deposits", "Mineral Deposits", "Superficial Imperfection", "Scratch", "Scored", "Crack", "Axial Crack", "Radial Crack", "Circumferencial Crack", "Chordwise Crack", "Tip Connected Radial Crack", "Connected Loop Crack", "Full Crack", "Multi Cracks", "Tight Crack", "Burn", "Edge Burnback", "Burn Hole", "LE Burn Hole", "Burn Through Hole", "Burn Through", "Corrosion", "Discoloration", "Oxidation", "Sulphidation", "Erosion", "Blistering", "Pitting", "Peeling", "Ceramic Coating Detachment", "Missing Thermal Barrier Coating", "Tip rub", "Burr", "Curled", "Tip Curled", "Tip Corner Curled", "Missing Tip Corner", "Overlap", "Shingling", "Unlatching", "Out Of Flush", "Missing Material", "Missing Piece", "Chipped", "Flaking", "Lift Up", "Bulging", "Spalled", "Bent", "Distortion", "Tear", "Torn", "Wear", "Worn", "Plugged Air Slot", "Damper Wire Extrusion")
    Me.cmbHPC4_15.List = Array("Dent", "Nick", "Coating Damage", "Organic Redidues", "Dirt", "Trace", "Deposits", "Mineral Deposits", "Superficial Imperfection", "Scratch", "Scored", "Crack", "Axial Crack", "Radial Crack", "Circumferencial Crack", "Chordwise Crack", "Tip Connected Radial Crack", "Connected Loop Crack", "Full Crack", "Multi Cracks", "Tight Crack", "Burn", "Edge Burnback", "Burn Hole", "LE Burn Hole", "Burn Through Hole", "Burn Through", "Corrosion", "Discoloration", "Oxidation", "Sulphidation", "Erosion", "Blistering", "Pitting", "Peeling", "Ceramic Coating Detachment", "Missing Thermal Barrier Coating", "Tip rub", "Burr", "Curled", "Tip Curled", "Tip Corner Curled", "Missing Tip Corner", "Overlap", "Shingling", "Unlatching", "Out Of Flush", "Missing Material", "Missing Piece", "Chipped", "Flaking", "Lift Up", "Bulging", "Spalled", "Bent", "Distortion", "Tear", "Torn", "Wear", "Worn", "Plugged Air Slot", "Damper Wire Extrusion")
    Me.cmbHPC4_16.List = Array("Dent", "Nick", "Coating Damage", "Organic Redidues", "Dirt", "Trace", "Deposits", "Mineral Deposits", "Superficial Imperfection", "Scratch", "Scored", "Crack", "Axial Crack", "Radial Crack", "Circumferencial Crack", "Chordwise Crack", "Tip Connected Radial Crack", "Connected Loop Crack", "Full Crack", "Multi Cracks", "Tight Crack", "Burn", "Edge Burnback", "Burn Hole", "LE Burn Hole", "Burn Through Hole", "Burn Through", "Corrosion", "Discoloration", "Oxidation", "Sulphidation", "Erosion", "Blistering", "Pitting", "Peeling", "Ceramic Coating Detachment", "Missing Thermal Barrier Coating", "Tip rub", "Burr", "Curled", "Tip Curled", "Tip Corner Curled", "Missing Tip Corner", "Overlap", "Shingling", "Unlatching", "Out Of Flush", "Missing Material", "Missing Piece", "Chipped", "Flaking", "Lift Up", "Bulging", "Spalled", "Bent", "Distortion", "Tear", "Torn", "Wear", "Worn", "Plugged Air Slot", "Damper Wire Extrusion")
    Me.cmbHPC4_17.List = Array("Dent", "Nick", "Coating Damage", "Organic Redidues", "Dirt", "Trace", "Deposits", "Mineral Deposits", "Superficial Imperfection", "Scratch", "Scored", "Crack", "Axial Crack", "Radial Crack", "Circumferencial Crack", "Chordwise Crack", "Tip Connected Radial Crack", "Connected Loop Crack", "Full Crack", "Multi Cracks", "Tight Crack", "Burn", "Edge Burnback", "Burn Hole", "LE Burn Hole", "Burn Through Hole", "Burn Through", "Corrosion", "Discoloration", "Oxidation", "Sulphidation", "Erosion", "Blistering", "Pitting", "Peeling", "Ceramic Coating Detachment", "Missing Thermal Barrier Coating", "Tip rub", "Burr", "Curled", "Tip Curled", "Tip Corner Curled", "Missing Tip Corner", "Overlap", "Shingling", "Unlatching", "Out Of Flush", "Missing Material", "Missing Piece", "Chipped", "Flaking", "Lift Up", "Bulging", "Spalled", "Bent", "Distortion", "Tear", "Torn", "Wear", "Worn", "Plugged Air Slot", "Damper Wire Extrusion")
    Me.cmbHPC4_18.List = Array("Dent", "Nick", "Coating Damage", "Organic Redidues", "Dirt", "Trace", "Deposits", "Mineral Deposits", "Superficial Imperfection", "Scratch", "Scored", "Crack", "Axial Crack", "Radial Crack", "Circumferencial Crack", "Chordwise Crack", "Tip Connected Radial Crack", "Connected Loop Crack", "Full Crack", "Multi Cracks", "Tight Crack", "Burn", "Edge Burnback", "Burn Hole", "LE Burn Hole", "Burn Through Hole", "Burn Through", "Corrosion", "Discoloration", "Oxidation", "Sulphidation", "Erosion", "Blistering", "Pitting", "Peeling", "Ceramic Coating Detachment", "Missing Thermal Barrier Coating", "Tip rub", "Burr", "Curled", "Tip Curled", "Tip Corner Curled", "Missing Tip Corner", "Overlap", "Shingling", "Unlatching", "Out Of Flush", "Missing Material", "Missing Piece", "Chipped", "Flaking", "Lift Up", "Bulging", "Spalled", "Bent", "Distortion", "Tear", "Torn", "Wear", "Worn", "Plugged Air Slot", "Damper Wire Extrusion")
    Me.cmbHPC4_19.List = Array("Dent", "Nick", "Coating Damage", "Organic Redidues", "Dirt", "Trace", "Deposits", "Mineral Deposits", "Superficial Imperfection", "Scratch", "Scored", "Crack", "Axial Crack", "Radial Crack", "Circumferencial Crack", "Chordwise Crack", "Tip Connected Radial Crack", "Connected Loop Crack", "Full Crack", "Multi Cracks", "Tight Crack", "Burn", "Edge Burnback", "Burn Hole", "LE Burn Hole", "Burn Through Hole", "Burn Through", "Corrosion", "Discoloration", "Oxidation", "Sulphidation", "Erosion", "Blistering", "Pitting", "Peeling", "Ceramic Coating Detachment", "Missing Thermal Barrier Coating", "Tip rub", "Burr", "Curled", "Tip Curled", "Tip Corner Curled", "Missing Tip Corner", "Overlap", "Shingling", "Unlatching", "Out Of Flush", "Missing Material", "Missing Piece", "Chipped", "Flaking", "Lift Up", "Bulging", "Spalled", "Bent", "Distortion", "Tear", "Torn", "Wear", "Worn", "Plugged Air Slot", "Damper Wire Extrusion")
    Me.cmbHPC4_20.List = Array("Dent", "Nick", "Coating Damage", "Organic Redidues", "Dirt", "Trace", "Deposits", "Mineral Deposits", "Superficial Imperfection", "Scratch", "Scored", "Crack", "Axial Crack", "Radial Crack", "Circumferencial Crack", "Chordwise Crack", "Tip Connected Radial Crack", "Connected Loop Crack", "Full Crack", "Multi Cracks", "Tight Crack", "Burn", "Edge Burnback", "Burn Hole", "LE Burn Hole", "Burn Through Hole", "Burn Through", "Corrosion", "Discoloration", "Oxidation", "Sulphidation", "Erosion", "Blistering", "Pitting", "Peeling", "Ceramic Coating Detachment", "Missing Thermal Barrier Coating", "Tip rub", "Burr", "Curled", "Tip Curled", "Tip Corner Curled", "Missing Tip Corner", "Overlap", "Shingling", "Unlatching", "Out Of Flush", "Missing Material", "Missing Piece", "Chipped", "Flaking", "Lift Up", "Bulging", "Spalled", "Bent", "Distortion", "Tear", "Torn", "Wear", "Worn", "Plugged Air Slot", "Damper Wire Extrusion")
    Me.cmbHPC4_21.List = Array("EM TASK 72-00-00-200-002-B00", "AMM 72-00-00-200-016-B", "AMM 72-00-00-200-016-B01")
    Me.cmbHPC4_22.List = Array("EM TASK 72-00-00-200-002-B00", "AMM 72-00-00-200-016-B", "AMM 72-00-00-200-016-B01")
    Me.cmbHPC4_23.List = Array("EM TASK 72-00-00-200-002-B00", "AMM 72-00-00-200-016-B", "AMM 72-00-00-200-016-B01")
    Me.cmbHPC4_24.List = Array("EM TASK 72-00-00-200-002-B00", "AMM 72-00-00-200-016-B", "AMM 72-00-00-200-016-B01")
    Me.cmbHPC4_25.List = Array("EM TASK 72-00-00-200-002-B00", "AMM 72-00-00-200-016-B", "AMM 72-00-00-200-016-B01")
    Me.cmbHPC4_26.List = Array("EM TASK 72-00-00-200-002-B00", "AMM 72-00-00-200-016-B", "AMM 72-00-00-200-016-B01")
    Me.cmbHPC4_27.List = Array("EM TASK 72-00-00-200-002-B00", "AMM 72-00-00-200-016-B", "AMM 72-00-00-200-016-B01")
    Me.cmbHPC4_28.List = Array("EM TASK 72-00-00-200-002-B00", "AMM 72-00-00-200-016-B", "AMM 72-00-00-200-016-B01")
    Me.cmbHPC4_29.List = Array("EM TASK 72-00-00-200-002-B00", "AMM 72-00-00-200-016-B", "AMM 72-00-00-200-016-B01")
    Me.cmbHPC4_30.List = Array("EM TASK 72-00-00-200-002-B00", "AMM 72-00-00-200-016-B", "AMM 72-00-00-200-016-B01")
End Sub
```

What can be cause this issue?

Comment: Try exporting and removing the user form from the project. Close and re-open the project and then import the form. You also need to clean up your code. Instead of listing each array of items 10 times do it once by assigning the arrays to variables and then assign the variable to the list. You will then have less code which will be simpler to maintain.

Comment: Dependent on the document design I would be inclined to use content controls wrapped in a repeating section content control rather than a user form.

Comment: Out of context, the array has an organic redidues, typo for residues I believe.

Comment: The "out of memory" error message tends to be generic and often has nothing to do with memory. It is a default error code when a specific code was not written for the real error. BTW, that appears to be quite the userform, on the order of the old wizards!

Comment: @TimothyRylatt Thanks for your comment. I split each page to new UserForm and the problem solved for now.